# Apply transformation to CSS element after previous transformation ended

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to chain together 2 transforms, but I want the 2nd one to begin after the 1st one ends.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
.trailingNote {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  background:black;
  width:20px;
  transition: transform  5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;

  }
.trailingNote-moveUp{
  transform: scaleY(10) translateY(-200px);
}
```

Basically, I want the element to be scaled by 10 on the y axis, then, after scaleY ends, start translateY(-200px) to move the scaled element up.

Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/Sederfo/pen/abqOoOP

Comment: Sounds like [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CSS keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```js
function startAnimation() {
  var element = document.getElementById("x");
  element.classList.add("trailingNote-moveUp");
}
```

```css
.trailingNote {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  background:black;
  width: 20px;
}
 
.trailingNote:hover, .trailingNote-moveUp {
  animation: animate 5s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(10);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(10) translateY(-200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="x" class="trailingNote">Note</div>
<button onclick="startAnimation()">Animate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed!
Could you also please point me in the right direction about using animation-timing-function linear so both animations have the same speed from start to end in this keyframe context?

Comment: @Sederfo I updated my answer to make the animation linear

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    box.classList.add('transform-1');
    box.addEventListener('transitionend', () =>{
        setTimeout(function (){
            box.classList.add('transform-2');
        },1000)
    })
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.box{
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: brown;
  transition: all  1s linear;
}

.transform-1{
  transform: scaleY(5);
}

.transform-2{
  transform: translateY(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box"></div>
<button>Click me</button>
```